# Shell: replace \n with space between two specific lines

Tags: shell

This is my first post here, thanks in advance for your prompt support.

I did some greps on a big file and came with file like the below. I want to make all lines after that starting with XX@ in the same line.

So, I want the flowing:

```
XX@DEV1> 
Feb 23 07:00:03
Feb 23 07:00:05
Sent : 4608
Received : 4227
Feb 23 07:00:07
Feb 23 07:00:09

XX@DEV2> 
Feb 23 07:00:32
Feb 23 07:00:34
Sent : 4608
Received : 4232
Feb 23 07:00:36
Feb 23 07:00:38

XX@DEV1> 
Feb 23 08:00:03
Feb 23 08:00:06
Sent : 4608
Received : 4265
Feb 23 08:00:07
Feb 23 08:00:09

XX@DEV2>
...
```

To become:

```
XX@DEV1> Feb 23 07:00:03 Feb 23 07:00:05 Sent : 4608 Received : 4227 Feb 23 07:00:07 Feb 23 07:00:09

XX@DEV2> Feb 23 07:00:32 Feb 23 07:00:34 Sent : 4608 Received : 4232 Feb 23 07:00:36 Feb 23 07:00:38

XX@DEV1> Feb 23 08:00:03 Feb 23 08:00:06 Sent : 4608 Received : 4265 Feb 23 08:00:07 Feb 23 08:00:09

XX@DEV2> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with *awk* pretty easily:

```
awk '/^XX/{if(length(out))print out;out=$0;next}{out=out" "$0}END{print out}' yourfile
```

That says.. if the line starts with "XX", print whatever we have accumluated in variable `out`, then save current line in variable `out`. If the line is anything else, append it to variable `out` after adding a space. At the end, print whatever we have accumulated in variable `out`.

Output:

```
XX@DEV1>  Feb 23 07:00:03 Feb 23 07:00:05 Sent : 4608 Received : 4227 Feb 23 07:00:07 Feb 23    07:00:09
XX@DEV2>  Feb 23 07:00:32 Feb 23 07:00:34 Sent : 4608 Received : 4232 Feb 23 07:00:36 Feb 23 07:00:38
XX@DEV1>  Feb 23 08:00:03 Feb 23 08:00:06 Sent : 4608 Received : 4265 Feb 23 08:00:07 Feb 23 08:00:09
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it *bash* in much the same way as the *awk* in my other answer:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    if [[ $line == XX* ]] ;then
      echo $OUT         # Output whatever we have accumulated in $OUT
      OUT=$line         # Zero out $OUT and restart accumulating
    else
      OUT="$OUT $line"  # Append this line to $OUT
    fi
done < yourfile
echo $OUT               # Output any trailing stuff at the end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '
  # use -n to prevent sed from printing each line
  # if the line read starts with XX, go (b) to :printit
  /^XX/ b printit
  # if it is the last line ($), also go to :printit
  $ b printit
  # for all other lines, append the read line to the hold space (H)
  # and then go to the :end (so we read the next line)
  H; b end

:printit {
  # swap the hold and the pattern space
  x
  # replace all (s/../../g) single or multiple newlines (\n\n*)
  #   with a space
  s/\n\n*/ /g
  # print the pattern space
  p
}

:end
' your_file
```